# How to send live audio stream to IBM Watson Speech-To-Text immediately without saving audio file locally using C# and IBM Watson SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, naudio

I have a requirement to use IBM Watson SDK to record the audio using microphone and send it to IBM Watson speech-to-text using C#. I am able to achieve this functionality by saving the audio file locally and then sending it using **NAudio** library. But my requirement is to use streaming mode to send live audio to IBM Watson Speech-to-Text service without storing the audio file physically.
I am not able to find **RecognizeUsingWebSocket** service in the SDK. I am able to find only **Recognize** service.

Below is my code which is used to save audio file locally.

Can anyone please help me to achieve it ?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IBM.Cloud.SDK.Core.Authentication.Iam;
using IBM.Watson.Assistant.v1.Model;
using IBM.Watson.Assistant.v1;
using IBM.Cloud.SDK.Core.Authentication.Bearer;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using IBM.Cloud.SDK.Core.Http;
using IBM.Watson.SpeechToText.v1;

namespace watsonConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        string apikey = "";
        string sttApiKey = "";
        string url = "";
        string stturl = "";
        string versionDate = "";
        string workspaceId = "";

        static public AssistantService service;
        static public SpeechToTextService sttservice;
        private WaveInEvent waveIn;
        private WaveFormat format = new WaveFormat(16000, 16, 1);
        private ClientWebSocket ws;

        static public WaveFileWriter waveFile;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program pr = new Program();


            BearerTokenAuthenticator authenticator = new BearerTokenAuthenticator(
                bearerToken: pr.apikey);
            service = new AssistantService(pr.versionDate, authenticator);
            service.SetServiceUrl(pr.url);


            BearerTokenAuthenticator sttauthenticator = new BearerTokenAuthenticator(
            bearerToken: pr.sttApiKey);

            sttservice = new SpeechToTextService(sttauthenticator);
            sttservice.SetServiceUrl(pr.stturl);


            WaveInCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveIn.GetCapabilities(0);
            Console.WriteLine("Now recording...");
            WaveInEvent waveSource = new WaveInEvent();
            waveSource.DeviceNumber = 0;
            waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);

            waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);

            string tempFile = (@"C:/watsonConsole/bin/Debug/test/testaudiotest.wav");
            waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(tempFile, waveSource.WaveFormat);
            waveSource.StartRecording();
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to stop");
            Console.ReadLine();
            waveSource.StopRecording();
            waveFile.Dispose();
            pr.Recognize();

            Console.WriteLine("done");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        }

        public void StartRecording()
        {
            waveIn = new WaveInEvent
            {
                BufferMilliseconds = 50,
                DeviceNumber = 0,
                WaveFormat = format
            };

            waveIn.StartRecording();
        }               

        public void Recognize()
        {

            var result = sttservice.Recognize(
                audio: File.ReadAllBytes("test/testaudiotest.wav"),
                contentType: "audio/wav",
                wordAlternativesThreshold: 0.9f,
                languageCustomizationId: "",
                acousticCustomizationId: "",
                customizationWeight: 0.7,
                smartFormatting: true
    );
        

            Console.WriteLine(result.Response);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: You should look a bit better, RecognizeUsingWebSocket is definitely there ;)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. Do you mean it is available inside this folder : dotnet-standard-sdk-master?

Comment: Try this https://gist.github.com/arjun-g/75961830d363cc9265e4ac2ca095168b

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes, i saw the code. i noticed that it is loading from the physical audio file. Correct me if i am wrong. Would it be possible to update the code which i have posted to record live audio and send ?

Comment: Sure, just replace File.read with Naudio.read

Comment: Thanks for the support. If you don't mind, can you please let me know how i can pass live audio which i recorded to NAudio.read() method. I am new to C# so i am finding it bit tough.